# Facebook PHP SDK & Page feed post (filtering results)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

Facebook PHP SDK & Page feed post (filtering results)

Greetings! I've been working lately on an effective way to implement a Facebook public page feed (each post featuring description, date and picture) on a website. 
I've put put together the following code wich allows me to use a foreach on $elements.

```
$pageid = '#PAGEID#';
$accesstoken = '#ACCESSTOKEN#';
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/$pageid/feed?limit=20&access_token=$accesstoken";

function getfb($url){

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, '');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    $raw_xml = curl_exec($curl); // execute the curl command
    $result = json_decode($raw_xml, true);

    return $result;
}

$elements = getfb($url);
foreach($elements['data'] as $k => $v){
    $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/{$v['id']}?fields=full_picture,picture&access_token=$accesstoken";
    $fields = getfb($url);
    $elements['data'][$k]['pictures'] = $fields;
}

var_dump($elements);
```

It does work nicely, but unfortunately instead of listing only the posts published on the page by the owner, it also lists posts published inside the box "Visitor Posts"... which I do not want.
Do you know and/or can help me figure out how to filter those results in such a way to only list posts published by page owner?

Thank you very much!

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/feed // FYI, that this is far from “efficient” if you were to do this on every page load, without implementing any caching on your end, should be obvious. You are very likely to run into the API rate limits with that.

Comment: why not just put this in ONE call instead of that weird foreach? > pageid/feed?fields=message,full_picture,picture

Comment: If i'm not asking too much, could you spare a few minutes and show me to correct way to do so? I've been struggling a lot implementing these API and I would really appeciate if you could lend me and hand.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestions Luschn and CBroe posted I kept on reading/looking and endend up using the following code. I'm not sure yet if this is the correct/best way of doing so, but it does seem to working nicely.

```
require_once ('facebook/autoload.php'); // See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/

$facebook_page_id           = 'xxx';
$facebook_app_secret        = 'yyy';
$facebook_app_id            = 'zzz';
$facebook_graph_version     = 'v2.6';

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => $facebook_app_id,
    'app_secret' => $facebook_app_secret,
    'default_graph_version' => $facebook_graph_version
]);

$response = $fb->get( '/'.$facebook_page_id.'/posts?fields=message,full_picture,link,updated_time,picture&limit=5', $fb->getApp()->getAccessToken() );

$get_data = $response->getDecodedBody(); // for Array resonse

foreach ( $get_data['data'] as $single ) {

    var_dump($single);

}
```